# WORDPRESS: How to add an existing page to navigation menu programmatically, for once

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to add an existing page to the header menu via backend. How can I do that? what functions are available to achieve this?

And I need to add it once to the link at the end of it.

Thanks.

Comment: _“what functions are available to achieve this?”_ - have you done any research on this? Considering that googling for “add page to wp menu” already brings https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/ as one of the top results, I rather doubt you did.

Comment: Honestly I'm a beginner at this, I'm just looking for the right solution, I did my research but I want to know how would I use this in functions.php file. Also I want to clarify that I want to add a new menu item in the header nav menu by coding

Comment: _“but I want to know how would I use this in functions.php file”_ - well what parameters it takes is described there, so what more do you need to know now in this regard? (Whether this would be a good place to do this in the first place, remains to be seen - it _might_ end up adding a new menu item on every page load … but you’ll find that out once you start testing it.)

Comment: I have a webpage, where I currently have "ABout us", "Home", "Contact", and I want to add the existing page "Profile" at the end of this menu only once. The default wordpress dashboard is not accessible to me, that is why I am opting for this approach

Comment: So this is a one-time thing, that will never get repeated? Then it would make way more sense to ask someone who actually has back-end access to just add it to the menu, no? You will need someone with back-end access anyway, to fix things, if what you try does not succeed at first, and you add the wrong page or in the wrong place … (not if you properly set up a development system first of course.)